# Does there exist a math version of `multido` command?

Tags: amsmath

I need a command as `\hdotsfor` and use it in `align` environment.

```
\begin{align*}
X&=a_{11} + a_{12} + \cdots + a_{1n}\\
&\qquad{}+ a_{21} + a_{22} + \cdots + a_{2n}\\
&\text{\multido{}{33}{$\cdot$}}\\
&\qquad{}+ a_{m1} + a_{m2} + \cdots + a_{mn}
\end{align*}
```

The spacing between dot is not correct. While

```
\begin{align*}
X&=a_{11} + a_{12} + \cdots + a_{1n}\\
&\qquad{}+ a_{21} + a_{22} + \cdots + a_{2n}\\
&\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\\
&\qquad{}+ a_{m1} + a_{m2} + \cdots + a_{mn}
\end{align*}
```

is correct. So I think may be the math environment take a bad effect.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to begin your questions with a greeting.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{align*}
X &= a_{11} + a_{12} + \cdots + a_{1n}\\
  & \qquad{}+ a_{21} + a_{22} + \cdots + a_{2n}\\
  & \makebox[5cm]{\dotfill}\\
  & \qquad{}+ a_{m1} + a_{m2} + \cdots + a_{mn}
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `\multido` works in math mode, so removing `\text` and the dollars from your example gives the correct spacing, except for the last dot. This is fixed by adding an empty math atom at the end (with `{}`). Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
X&=a_{11} + a_{12} + \cdots + a_{1n}\\
&\qquad{}+ a_{21} + a_{22} + \cdots + a_{2n}\\
&\multido{}{33}{\cdot} {}\\
&\qquad{}+ a_{m1} + a_{m2} + \cdots + a_{mn}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I would say, though that using `\vdots` in this case is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft 
X=a_{11} + a_{12} + \cdots + a_{1n}\\
&+ a_{21} + a_{22} + \cdots + a_{2n}\\
&\text{\multido{}{23}{$\cdot\,$}}\\
&+ a_{m1} + a_{m2} + \cdots + a_{mn}
\end{align*}
```