# Putting row of dots in an equation

Tags: equations, punctuation

Is it possible create a system of equations that will look like this:

```
aX(x_0)+bX(x_0)+cX(x_0)=A
dX(x_1)+eX(x_1)+fX(x_1)=B
.........................
gX(x_n)+hX(x_n)+iX(x_n)=B
```

I tried with this:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    a_0\varphi_0(x_0)+a_1\varphi_1(x_0)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_0)&=f_0\\
    a_0\varphi_0(x_1)+a_1\varphi_1(x_1)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_1)&=f_1\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate sep={0.4mm}{2mm},fill] (6,0) -- (12,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    a_0\varphi_0(x_n)+a_1\varphi_1(x_n)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_n)&=f_n\\
    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
    \end{document}
```

But that isn't working :
I could just put `\cdots` or some similar dots, but I'd like a continuous line across the row.

Comment: one possibility here: [Does there exist a math version of `multido` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15582/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton all three answers there require hand-tuned values. An automatic solution would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can treat the alignment as an array, and use `\hdotsfor` (defined by `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rl}
 a_0\varphi_0(x_0)+a_1\varphi_1(x_0)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_0)&{}=f_0\\
 a_0\varphi_0(x_1)+a_1\varphi_1(x_1)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_1)&{}=f_1\\
 \hdotsfor{2}\\
 a_0\varphi_0(x_n)+a_1\varphi_1(x_n)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_n)&{}=f_n\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

since it's necessary to reset `\arraycolset` to zero, that needs to be hidden within a group.  although you could use `{ ... }`, unless you put a `%` after the closing brace, a line of text that follows directly after will be indented by one space; i used `\begingroup ... \endgroup` to take advantage of the fact that the space (or end of line) following `\endgroup` will be ignored.

of course, this won't work if you want the lines numbered individually.

Comment: All the answers are great! I don't need numbering, so it's great. I've chosen this as correct, it seemed like the easiest to implement :D (no tikz needed). Thank you all, you all got an upvote :D

Answer (score 4):

This is an option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{*{3}{c@{\;+\:}}c@{\;=\;}c}
a_{1,1}x_{1} & a_{1,2}x_{2} & \cdots & a_{1,n}x_{n} & b_1 \\ 
a_{2,1}x_{1} & a_{2,2}x_{2} & \cdots & a_{2,n}x_{n} & b_2 \\ 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\dotfill} \\
a_{n,1}x_{1} & a_{n,2}x_{2} & \cdots & a_{n,n}x_{n} & b_n \\ 
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[How to draw a line of dots in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25642/how-to-draw-a-line-of-dots-in-tikz)
 shows how to draw such a line. Maybe another alternative would be to use `hdashrule` from the `dashrule` package?

```
\intertext{\hdashrule{8cm}{1pt}{1mm 1mm}}
```

instead of the `tikzpicture` may be good enough but still requires a hard-coded width.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using TikZ with your settings. Simply put some marks at the start and ending of the previous line and then use `\mdotteline` for those marks:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate (#1);}
\newcommand\mdottedline[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path let \p1=(#1), \p2=(#2) in
  node [text width=\x2-\x1]  at ( $ ([yshift=-\baselineskip]#1)!0.5!([yshift=-\baselineskip]#2) $ ) {\dotfill};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
a_0\varphi_0(x_0)+a_1\varphi_1(x_0)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_0)&=f_0\\
\tikzmark{start}a_0\varphi_0(x_1)+a_1\varphi_1(x_1)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_1)&=f_1\tikzmark{end}
\\ \\
a_0\varphi_0(x_n)+a_1\varphi_1(x_n)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_n)&=f_n
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align}
a_0\varphi_0(x_0)+a_1\varphi_1(x_0)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_0)&=f_0\\
\tikzmark{starti}a_0\varphi_0(x_1)+a_1\varphi_1(x_1)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_1)&=f_1\tikzmark{endi}
\\ \notag\\
a_0\varphi_0(x_n)+a_1\varphi_1(x_n)+\ldots+a_n\varphi_n(x_n)&=f_n
\end{align}

\mdottedline{start}{end}
\mdottedline{starti}{endi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As the example shows, this works whether you number your lines or not.

Comment: This one is great if I need numbered lines separately :)